# Find the maximum result after collapsing an array with subtractions

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

Given an array of integers, I need to reduce it to a single number by repeatedly replacing any two numbers with their difference, to produce the maximum possible result.

Example1 - If I have array of [0,-1,-1,-1] then performing (0-(-1)) then (1-(-1)) and then (2-(-1)) will give 3 as maximum possible output

Example2- [3,2,1,1] we can get maximum output as 5 { first (1-1) then (0-2) then (3-(-2)}

Can someone tell me how to solve this question?

Comment: I do not understand the instruction or the algorithm you describe. "I have an array and we need to reduce it to a single number by subtracting any 2 numbers from it and the end result should be maximum" is unclear and the examples do not seem to use the same algorithm to get to the result of 3.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa I have a few more examples: `[14, 8, -4, -5]` then `(-5) - (8) = (-13)` so `[14, -4, -13]` then `(14) - (-13) = 27` so `[27, -4]` which has a difference of 31. This is opposed to the minimum possible final value, which is `(-5) - (14) = (-19)` so `[8, -4, -19]` then `(8) - (-4) = (12)` so `[12, -19]` which has a difference of -31. Other possible final values include 15 (for subtracting left to right), -23 (for subtracting right to left), `( 8 - (-4) ) - ( (-5) - 14 ) = 7`, etc.

Comment: Thnaks, I understand now.

Comment: any constraint like first element index should be less than second element index is there??

Comment: @user229204 No any other constraint

Comment: @ChristopherMarley Yes this is what question says. Can you please help me out to solve it

Comment: In the 2nd example, I am getting a maximum result of 5: `1-1 = 0` then `0-2 = -2` then `3-(-2) = 5`. Am I misunderstanding something ?

Comment: Yeah u are correct. Sorry It was my mistake

Answer (score 3):

The goal is to find the maximum result after iteratively substracting two numbers in an array.

The problem is mainly at the algorithmic level.
It is clear that the final result is bounded by the sum of the absolute values:

```
Bound = sum_i abs(a[i])
```

According to the rule `x - y`, the signs may change frequently. The algorithm must focus on maximizing the sum of absolute remaining values.

The key point is to consider what happens when we decide to *pair* two numbers.  If the signs of the numbers are different, the result will have a maximum absolute value, and we can decide the sign. For example, if the two values are (-5, 10), we will get `15` or `-15`. Associating numbers with a different sign, we just have to select the final sign in such a way that it is different from the sign of another number, for example the neighboor one.

The consequence is that if not all the signs are equal, we can manage that the result is equal to the bound. For example:

```
1 2 -3 4 5 -6 7 -> pair 2 and -3
1 -5 4 5 -6 7   -> pair 1 and -5
-6 4 5 -6 7
-10 5 -6 7
15 -6 7
-21 7
28 = Bound
```

If all the signs are equal, the bound cannot be attained. However, it is possible to minimize the loss by selecting as first number the one with the lowest absolute value. For example:

```
 3 4 1 2 2  -> pair 1 and 2
 3 4 -1 2   -> pair -1 and 2
 3 4 -3
 3 -7
 10 = Bound - 2*1
```

The same procedure can be used if all signs are negative. The point is that after this first "operation", we get a new bound, which can be attained thanks to the "sign rule".

In this situation (all signs equal), the result is equal to the bound minus twice the minimum absolute value.

Of course, one has to treat the `n = 1` case separately : `result = a[0];`

From that, writing a programme is rather easy.

Comment: Added your method to my code that compares with brute force.

Answer (score 2):

Consider an "anchor" an element we chose to string an arbitrary number of subtractions to.

Then clearly:

```
(Anchor1 - neg1 - neg2 - neg3...) - (Anchor2 - pos1 - pos2 - pos3...)
```

is optimal if

```
Anchor1 = max(array) and Anchor2 = min(array)
```

JavaScript code demonstrating the method by comparing it with brute force as well as Damien's [great method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59191473/2034787) (might not correctly handle arrays with all identical elements):

```js
function bruteForce(A){
  if (A.length == 1)
    return A[0]
  let best = -Infinity
  for (let i=1; i<A.length; i++){
    for (let j=0; j<i; j++){
      let A1 = A.slice()
      let A2 = A.slice()
      A1[i] -= A1[j]
      A1.splice(j, 1)
      A2[j] -= A2[i]
      A2.splice(i, 1)
      best = Math.max(
        best, bruteForce(A1), bruteForce(A2))
    }
  }
  return best
}

function f(A){
  let max = [-Infinity, -1]
  let min = [Infinity, -1]
  
  A.map(function(x, i){
    if (x > max[0])
      max = [x, i]
    if (x < min[0])
      min = [x, i]
  })
  
  let restPos = 0
  let restNeg = 0
  
  A.map(function(x, i){
    if (i != max[1] && i != min[1]){
      if (x >= 0)
        restPos += x
      else
        restNeg += x
    }
  })
  
  return (max[0] - restNeg) - (min[0] - restPos)
}

function damien(A){
  let absSum = 0
  let minAbs = Infinity
  let allSignsEqual = true
  let firstSign = A[0] > 0
  
  A.map(function(x, i){
    absSum += Math.abs(x)
    minAbs = Math.min(minAbs, Math.abs(x))
    if ((x > 0) != firstSign)
      allSignsEqual = false
  })
  
  return allSignsEqual ? absSum - 2*minAbs : absSum
}

var n = 6
var m = 10

for (let i=0; i<100; i++){
  let A = []
  for (let j=0; j<n; j++)
    A.push(~~(Math.random()*m) * [1,1][~~(Math.random()*2)])
  let a = bruteForce(A)
  let b = f(A)
  let c = damien(A)
  if (a != b || a != c)
    console.log(`Mismatch! ${a}, ${b}, ${c} :: ${A}`)
}

console.log("Done")
```

Comment: Interesting indeed. Are you getting the same result as my proposal ?

Comment: Two different approaches, two different algorithms for ordering operations, and same simple result (+1)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are fine, but here's another way to think about it:

If you expand the result into individual terms, you want all the positive numbers to end up as additive terms, and all the negative numbers to end up as subtractive terms.

If you have both signs available, then this is easy:

1. Subtract all but one of the positive numbers from a negative number
2. Subtract all of the negative numbers from the remaining positive number

If all your numbers have the same sign, then pick the one with the smallest absolute value at treat it as having the opposite sign in the above procedure.  That works out to:

1. If you have only negative numbers, then subtract them all from the least negative one; or
2. If you have only positive numbers, then subtract all but one from the smallest, and then subtract the result from the remaining one.